# How to find maximum-likelihood estimation

Tags: python-2.7, estimation, mle

There are 15 people. Each of them have been offered money. 4 of them agreed take a money. How to find maximum-likelihood estimation in the parameter p, using python

Comment: can you explicit the problem? give the input data you have and their format?

Comment: Yes. I do. It was a probability theory.